# Centering multiple div's inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV and inside that there are multiple div's that i want to center. Right now all the div's are aligned to left.

The CSS is:

```
 #statusInfo {
        background-color:#CCD8F5;
        color:black;
        clear:both;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px; 
    }
    #statusBox {
        padding: 2px 20px; 
        background: #84B88F;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
```

And HTML is:

```
<div id="statusInfo">
                <div style="display: table-row">
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">A1</div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">B2</div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">C1</div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">D1</div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">E1</div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">F1</div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">G1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you want your content centered in the child DIVs or you want the set of child DIVs to be centered in the `statusInfo` container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole thing inside a container div and give it `text-align: center;`
Then give `#statusInfo` `display: inline-block;`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="statusInfo">
        <!-- The rest of elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {text-align: center;}
#statusInfo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 0px;
    /* the rest of styles */
}
```

**P.s.** `ID` should be unique. So you might want to use class instead.  Instead of `id="statusBox"` use `class="statusBox"`.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/L0tb5ptm/1/)

**EDIT:**

Since you're using the table structure for inner divs, gives the "table" some `border-spacing` value:

```
#statusInfo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 0px;
    border-spacing: 10px 0px;
    /* the rest of styles */
}
```

[**UPDATED jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/L0tb5ptm/4/)

Comment: One more question. How can i give a small space between each DIV? So that it doesn't look like all touching each other!

Comment: Give `#statusInfo` - which plays the role of a table - some `border-spacing`. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all that display:table-row and display:table-cell.  Then just center it with display:inline-block on the inner divs and text-align:center on the outer.

```
#statusInfo {text-align:center;}
#statusBox {display:inline-block;}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hy53beu/

Answer (score 0):

```
 #statusInfo {
            background-color:#CCD8F5;
            color:black;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
        #statusBox {
            padding: 2px 20px;
            background: #84B88F;
            width: 30px;
            border-radius: 50px;

        }
        .inner_list{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

<div id="statusInfo">
    <div>
        <div class="inner_list">
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">A1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">B2</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">C1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">D1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">E1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">F1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" id="statusBox">G1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/831dd10e/